# SQL injection issue in java code

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have below main method which shows SQL injection flaw (as string concatenation is done here) when scanned for coding standards/rules.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean flag = false;
    String name = "";
    String subName = "abhi";

    try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("url","user", "password");

           if(flag==true){
               name = "LIKE '%'";
           } else {
               name = "= LOWER('" + subName + "')";
           }


            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE name "+name;

            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(":"+rs.getString(1));
            }
    }  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I want to remove the SQL injection flaw. As my `name` parameter is dynamic, I cannot set it with `preparedStatement`. What can be a optimal solution to this?

**NOTE**: Using 2 different queries in `if-else` block will not solve the purpose as I have 7 different parameters to be set dynamically which will introduce overhead as there will be many queries.

Comment: It's not overhead if it's necessary, though..

Comment: @FrederikVH but then it will be 42 (7x6) queries in total as every scenario should be handled

Answer (score 2):

> As my name parameter is dynamic, I cannot set it with preparedStatement.

Sure you can, you just need to treat both the SQL text and the parameters dynamically at the same time.

You should also use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), to correctly close the `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, and `ResultSet` objects.

```
boolean flag = false;
String subName = "abhi";

try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("url","user", "password")) {
    String sql = "SELECT *" +
                  " FROM xyz" +
                 " WHERE name " + (flag ? "LIKE '%'"
                                        : "= LOWER(?)");
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        if (! flag)
            s.setString(1, subName);
        try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(":"+rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

*FYI:* `WHERE name LIKE '%'` is the same as `WHERE name IS NOT NULL`, which is the same as no `WHERE` clause if the `name` column is not nullable.